# How to read the failure log message displayed when a system call failed in C++?

Tags: c++, linux

I have a C++ code that calls a test. I am doing a system call to execute this test. When this test fails, it will display something like this "  ERROR: One or more devices of following component type(s) could not be discovered:"

I have a C++ code that runs on Linux redhat and it is capable of detecting if the system call pass or failed. But it can not capture the error message (ERROR: One or more devices of following component type(s) could not be discovered:) and append into the log file or print it.

Can someone please tell me how to capture the error message (ERROR: One or more devices of following component type(s) could not be discovered:)? 
PS: I am an intern, any help would be really nice.

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main () 
{   
  int i;   
  if (system(NULL)) 
    puts ("Ok");   
  else 
    exit (1);

  i=system("hpsp --discover -verbose --user Admin --oapasswd password");  

  printf ("The value returned was: %d.\n",i);

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `system()` use [popen()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html).  This will open a pipe capturing the standard output of the test program so that your program can read it via the pipe.

Example **EDITED**:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE 1
#define BUFFSIZE 400

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *cmd = "hpsp --discover -verbose --user Admin --oapasswd password";

    char  buf[BUFFSIZE];
    char* searchResult;
     int  testPassed = 0;

    FILE *ptr;

    if ((ptr = popen(cmd, "r")) != NULL)
        while (fgets(buf, BUFFSIZE, ptr) != NULL)
        {
            if ((searchResult = strstr(buf, "The test passed")) != NULL )
            {
                testPassed = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

    if (testPassed)
        printf("yea!!\n");
    else
        printf("boo!!\n");

    pclose(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will just capture stdout of the command, not stderr.  If you want stderr, you can use a shell redirection such as `2>&1`, as popen uses the shell to run the command.

Comment: I need to not only capture stdout, but I also need to know if my system command passed or failed. I do like using popen(), but I am not sure how to figure out if my system command passed or failed. Could you please show me how to do that?

Comment: @usustarr - Just to be clear, there is no need to run system() because you are using popen() instead.  I don't know the specifics of the "passed" result string you will be searching for but I edited the code in the answer to illustrate how it would be done.

Comment: @usustarr, you're very welcome.  Best of luck with the internship.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dup` and `dup2` to backup/store the stderr file descriptor to redirect to your log file. Well, I'm guessing that errors go to stderr anyways.

Here's an example if you just want to write to a log file.

```
//open log file, choose whatever flags you need
int logfd = open("whateveryourlogfileis", O_APPEND);

//back up stderr file descriptor
int stderr_copy = dup(STDERR_FILENO);

//redirect stderr to your opened log file
dup2(logfd, STDERR_FILENO);

//close the original file descriptor for the log file
close(logfd);

//system call here

//restore stderr
dup2(stderr_copy, STDERR_FILENO);

//close stderr copy
close(stderr_copy);
```

Note: `dup2` closes the target file descriptor before `dup2`ing to it. `dup` just duplicates the file descriptor and returns to you the new file descriptor.